# How to fill dropdown after insert in db

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have one query insert in the partial and one drop down list in other partial That this 2 form show in one view. I want to fill drop down exactly after one data insert in db and show in drop down without page refresh.

Comment: You should follow some tutorials on http://asp.net, To achieve what you are after, you have to use AJAX. It is somewhat complicated if you are a newcomer. So try something first and then if you have questions, ask here with what you tried to do and why you think it didn't work.

Comment: ok sorry i'm new member. thanks